# Define a linear functional $T$ on $V$ by $Tv$ = $\langle v, u\rangle$. What is $T^∗ (\alpha)$ for a scalar $\alpha$ where $T^*$ is the adjoint.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators, riesz-representation-theorem

Now I do understand that the question might involve using Riesz representation as it involves a linear functional and we know that it can be written using an inner product. So $u$ is the representer of the linear functional in this case. So I think I might be able to find $u$ iff I know the orthonormal basis of $V$(which is not given). That brings me to my current roadblock.

Also even if I were to assume the orthonormal basis how would I use it to figure out $T^*$($\alpha$). Is there some kind of relation between them.

PS: I know what adjoint is but how do I use it to figure out the adjoint of $T^*(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition $\langle T^{*}\alpha, x \rangle= \alpha Tx$ since the inner product of two scalars is just their ordinary product. Hence $\langle T^{*}\alpha, x \rangle= \alpha \langle x, u \rangle$ which shows that $T^{*}\alpha=\alpha u$. [This proof is when the scalar field is $\mathbb R$. I will let you show that the answer is same when the scalar field is $\mathbb C$].

Comment: But this just proves that $\langle T^*\alpha - \alpha u , x \rangle$ is zero. You cannot say by using the equation  $\langle T^*\alpha , x \rangle = \langle x , \alpha u \rangle $ that $T^*\alpha = \alpha u$

Comment: $\langle T^{*}\alpha -\alpha u, x \rangle= 0$ **for all** $x$ implies that $ T^{*}\alpha=\alpha u$.  Just put $x= T^{*}\alpha-\alpha u$ to prove this. @RajeshSri

Comment: Also, I think you have used the property $\langle x, u \rangle = \langle u, x \rangle $  which is true only for $\Bbb{R}$ space only. If that is assumed then, I think your answer is correct @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: @RajeshSri Yes, I did take the scalar field to be $\mathbb R$ in my argument but the final answer is true even when it is $\mathbb C$

Comment: I think it will be $\tilde{\alpha} u $ in the case of $\Bbb{C}$

Comment: @RajeshSri No, $\overline {\alpha}u$ is not even linear in $\alpha$ since  $\overline {i\alpha}=-i\overline {\alpha}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110852/discussion-between-rajesh-sri-and-kavi-rama-murthy).